# Visual Basic 2008 Opacity Failure

Tags: vb.net, timer, windows-vista, transparency

I have a 2 files here. One is my main form, and the other is a dialog I made. Now I'm trying to get enter code here the dialog to gradually obtain its transparency from a timer which I have on the dialong form:

```
If Me.Opacity = "100" Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity + 1
        End If
```

Then from my main form, if I push a button it would do this:

```
Dialog.Timer1.Enabled = True
        Dialog.Timer1.Start()
```

this does not seem to work. When I press the button, it does nothing.

Can someone find a solution to this?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because opacity measured between zero and one (`50% = 0.5`, `4% = 0.04`, `100% = 1` etc.)

Not to mention you compare opacity to the string `"100"` rather than to the number `100`.